# Updating the Declared null variable to Boolean

Tags: javascript

is this correct to declare a null variable and update it to Boolean in further functions in JavaScript like

```
var isAnswerd = null;
if(condition){ isAnswerd = true;}
if(another condition){ isAnswerd = false;}
```

I know that I can declare the variable true or false at very beginning but in this case I need to not do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript has 'dynamic types'

Unlike more strongly typed languages, such as C#, you can more easily assign the variable to any type.

For example:

```
var x;               // Now x is undefined
var x = 5;           // Now x is a Number
var x = "John";      // Now x is a String
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

Comment: lol - went to fix formatting but in 15 sec you already did it

Comment: Thanks Dan and just another quick question! null or undefined?! Which one is your recommendation to use at this case?

Comment: @Suffii, there are ways to check undefined, but I always found "undefined" ambiguity annoying, so always default to null when i need to check against it being initialized, or leaving "undefined" when I know it will be before I need to check it

Answer (score 1):

The way how javascript works, you dont need to pre-initialize variables.

What you can do is

```
if(condition){ isAnswerd = true;}
if(another condition){ isAnswerd = false;}
```

and finally

```
if(typeof(isAnswered) != "undefined"){
.. 
}
```

or

```
if(condition){ isAnswerd = true;}

if(typeof(isAnswered) != "undefined"){
.. 
}
else{
..
}
```

In the second example you are not declaring the variable for false conditions.